# A word for a person who talks themselves up but actually does nothing

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What do you call someone who talks themselves up but actually does nothing?

Answer (score 1):

The word for this would probably be "Blowhard."

Answer (score 0):

An idiom commonly used for a *smooth talker* is *great boaster, little doer*.

If you are looking for some uncommon expression, you may refer to a **loquacious lazybones**.

Answer (score 0):

An adjective that can be used to define a person who only talks but does not work is "garrulous".

The meaning as given by Google is: excessively talkative, especially on trivial matters.
The usage of the  word would be "a garrulous cab driver".

Comment: (1) It seems that this answers only half of the question.  For example, a cab driver could be garrulous and still do his job (and more). (2) Google is not an information source / reference.  If you quote a definition, identify the dictionary it actually came from.

Answer (score -1):

Pretentious also works as a single word.

" pre·ten·tious
prəˈten(t)SHəs/
adjective
attempting to impress by affecting greater importance, talent, culture, etc., than is actually possessed. "

Reference:
"Hearts of Ladd" by Ian Alford